# Correctness of "I had been X (profession) for some time"?

Tags: tense, past-perfect, past-continuous

Is it correct to say "I had been X (profession) for some time" when now I am not working as X?

Example:

> I had been karting driver for 7 years

Comment: In general, yes, but I have no idea what you mean by _karting driver._ And and _a_ would most likely come before the X (profession): I had been _a banker_ for 7 years before I became a dentist. OR I was _a banker_ for 7 years, but now I am a dentist.

Comment: Maybe its a go-kart or go-cart driver.

Comment: I think its OK, though you need an article (a/an/the) before the profession.

Comment: Thank you for the info about article, it is needed here. Karting is a kind of motor sport where small car called "kart" is used: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kart_racing

Comment: I have a feeling that using "had been" would occur in close proximity to another clause that says states what you're doing at the moment. "I'm a dentist now. I had been a banker for five years." "I had been a paediatrician for six years, then I became a speech pathologist."

Comment: Actually the context is close. The case now I am not a karting driver.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It does not sound ok to me (non native).

I think It should be either:

I had been a kart driver for 7 years

I had been driving karts for 7 years

(or "I have been..."  depending on the temporal context)

Comment: Thank you! Seems, that "I had been a kart driver for 7 years" is perfectly correct, as it sounds really nice and I think the tense is also correct. Thanx for an article. Then only question has left that is it possible to say "karting driver" instead of "kart driver"? As karting is sport, it is the same as "racing driver". Is "racing driver" correct? Thank you.

Comment: "To race" is a verb. So you can have "racing". I am not aware of the existence of the verb "To kart". But being you in the field, maybe you can tell. If you instead use the legitimate noun "go-karting", perhaps you might form the term "go-karting driver", but I am a non native speaker (foreigner), so a native should confirm that. I don't really know.

Comment: Also, seems that in US and Western world the sport is called "go-karting", while in Russia and CIS its called "karting". Thank you for clarification.